# How to enable keyboard navigation for bxslider?

Tags: jquery, navigation, keyboard, bxslider

I'm using bxslider and added two buttons called #slider-next and #slider-prev. The mouse click events work very well - when clicking the next slide appears and all my other code is executed. But I want to navigate with the keyboard arrows through the slideshow. Is that possible? If yes, how? I tried with:

```
/* enable keyboard navigation */ 
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow
                    $( "#slider-prev" ).click(); 
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 39) { //right arrow
                    $( "#slider-next" ).click(); 
                }
         });
```

All of my other code of my slider-prev and slider-next click function was executed BUT the next or previous picture of the slide didnt appear. Did I miss something?

Edit:
I looked through the bxslider documentary again and found:

> goToNextSlide Performs a "Next" slide transition
>
> example: slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(); slider.goToNextSlide();
>
> goToPrevSlide Performs a "Prev" slide transition
>
> example: slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(); slider.goToPrevSlide();

But after modifying my keyup function the browser crushed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution - Look  [here](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/pull/239/files#diff-849ec2d3bf2f5e66e772df3428bbaf74R300)

**Edit:**

If you have more than one slider on a page but only one visible and you don't want to go to the next slide with all sliders but only with the visible try this:

```
if(el.is(':visible')){
    el.goToPrevSlide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example you can use with the normal version of bxSlider:

```
    var slider = $("#yourSliderIDHere");

    slider.bxSlider({
      adaptiveHeight: true, // not needed for keyboard navigation, just for example
      onSliderLoad: function() {

          $("body").keydown(function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
                slider.goToPrevSlide();
              } else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
                slider.goToNextSlide();
              }
            });

      }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

Replace below code to your bxslider.js even you can enable or disable keyboard key on line no. 45.

```
!function(t){
var e={
}
, s={
    mode:"horizontal",slideSelector:"",infiniteLoop:!0,hideControlOnEnd:!1,speed:500,easing:null,slideMargin:0,startSlide:0,randomStart:!1,captions:!1,ticker:!1,tickerHover:!1,adaptiveHeight:!1,adaptiveHeightSpeed:500,video:!1,useCSS:!0,preloadImages:"visible",responsive:!0,touchEnabled:!0,swipeThreshold:50,oneToOneTouch:!0,preventDefaultSwipeX:!0,preventDefaultSwipeY:!1,keyboardEnabled:!0,pager:!0,pagerType:"full",pagerShortSeparator:" / ",pagerSelector:null,buildPager:null,pagerCustom:null,controls:!0,nextText:"Next",prevText:"Prev",nextSelector:null,prevSelector:null,autoControls:!1,startText:"Start",stopText:"Stop",autoControlsCombine:!1,autoControlsSelector:null,auto:!1,pause:4e3,autoStart:!0,autoDirection:"next",autoHover:!1,autoDelay:0,minSlides:1,maxSlides:1,moveSlides:0,slideWidth:0,onSliderLoad:function(){
    }
    ,onSlideBefore:function(){
    }
    ,onSlideAfter:function(){
    }
    ,onSlideNext:function(){
    }
    ,onSlidePrev:function(){
    }
}
;
t.fn.bxSlider=function(n){
    if(0==this.length)return this;
    if(this.length&gt;
    1)return this.each(function(){
        t(this).bxSlider(n)
    }
    ),this;
    var o={
    }
    ,r=this;
    e.el=this;
    var a=t(window).width(),l=t(window).height(),d=function(){
        o.settings=t.extend({
        }
        ,s,n),o.settings.slideWidth=parseInt(o.settings.slideWidth),o.children=r.children(o.settings.slideSelector),o.children.length&lt;
        o.settings.minSlides&&(o.settings.minSlides=o.children.length),o.children.length&lt;
        o.settings.maxSlides&&(o.settings.maxSlides=o.children.length),o.settings.randomStart&&(o.settings.startSlide=Math.floor(Math.random()*o.children.length)),o.active={
            index:o.settings.startSlide
        }
        ,o.carousel=o.settings.minSlides&gt;
        1||o.settings.maxSlides&gt;
        1,o.carousel&&(o.settings.preloadImages="all"),o.minThreshold=o.settings.minSlides*o.settings.slideWidth+(o.settings.minSlides-1)*o.settings.slideMargin,o.maxThreshold=o.settings.maxSlides*o.settings.slideWidth+(o.settings.maxSlides-1)*o.settings.slideMargin,o.working=!1,o.controls={
        }
        ,o.interval=null,o.animProp="vertical"==o.settings.mode?"top":"left",o.usingCSS=o.settings.useCSS&&"fade"!=o.settings.mode&&function(){
            var t=document.createElement("div"),e=["WebkitPerspective","MozPerspective","OPerspective","msPerspective"];
            for(var i in e)if(void 0!==t.style[e[i]])return o.cssPrefix=e[i].replace("Perspective","").toLowerCase(),o.animProp="-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transform",!0;
            return!1
        }
        (),"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&(o.settings.maxSlides=o.settings.minSlides),r.data("origStyle",r.attr("style")),r.children(o.settings.slideSelector).each(function(){
            t(this).data("origStyle",t(this).attr("style"))
        }
        ),c()
    }
    ,c=function(){
        r.wrap('<div class="bx-wrapper"><div class="bx-viewport"></div></div>'),o.viewport=r.parent(),o.loader=t('<div class="bx-loading" />'),o.viewport.prepend(o.loader),r.css({
            width:"horizontal"==o.settings.mode?100*o.children.length+215+"%":"auto",position:"relative"
        }
        ),o.usingCSS&&o.settings.easing?r.css("-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transition-timing-function",o.settings.easing):o.settings.easing||(o.settings.easing="swing");
        f();
        o.viewport.css({
            width:"100%",overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"
        }
        ),o.viewport.parent().css({
            maxWidth:p()
        }
        ),o.settings.pager||o.viewport.parent().css({
            margin:"0 auto 0px"
        }
        ),o.children.css({
            "float":"horizontal"==o.settings.mode?"left":"none",listStyle:"none",position:"relative"
        }
        ),o.children.css("width",u()),"horizontal"==o.settings.mode&&o.settings.slideMargin&gt;
        0&&o.children.css("marginRight",o.settings.slideMargin),"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&o.settings.slideMargin&gt;
        0&&o.children.css("marginBottom",o.settings.slideMargin),"fade"==o.settings.mode&&(o.children.css({
            position:"absolute",zIndex:0,display:"none"
        }
        ),o.children.eq(o.settings.startSlide).css({
            zIndex:50,display:"block"
        }
        )),o.controls.el=t('<div class="bx-controls" />'),o.settings.captions&&y(),o.active.last=o.settings.startSlide==x()-1,o.settings.video&&r.fitVids();
        var e=o.children.eq(o.settings.startSlide);
        "all"==o.settings.preloadImages&&(e=o.children),o.settings.ticker?o.settings.pager=!1:(o.settings.pager&&T(),o.settings.controls&&C(),o.settings.auto&&o.settings.autoControls&&E(),(o.settings.controls||o.settings.autoControls||o.settings.pager)&&o.viewport.after(o.controls.el)),g(e,h)
    }
    ,g=function(e,i){
        var s=e.find("img, iframe").length;
        if(0==s)return void i();
        var n=0;
        e.find("img, iframe").each(function(){
            t(this).is("img")&&t(this).attr("src",t(this).attr("src")+"?timestamp="+(new Date).getTime()),t(this).load(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    ++n==s&&i()
                }
                ,0)
            }
            )
        }
        )
    }
    ,h=function(){
        if(o.settings.infiniteLoop&&"fade"!=o.settings.mode&&!o.settings.ticker){
            var e="vertical"==o.settings.mode?o.settings.minSlides:o.settings.maxSlides,i=o.children.slice(0,e).clone().addClass("bx-clone"),s=o.children.slice(-e).clone().addClass("bx-clone");
            r.append(i).prepend(s)
        }
        o.loader.remove(),S(),"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&(o.settings.adaptiveHeight=!0),o.viewport.height(v()),r.redrawSlider(),o.settings.onSliderLoad(o.active.index),o.initialized=!0,o.settings.responsive&&t(window).bind("resize",B),o.settings.auto&&o.settings.autoStart&&H(),o.settings.ticker&&L(),o.settings.pager&&I(o.settings.startSlide),o.settings.controls&&W(),o.settings.touchEnabled&&!o.settings.ticker&&O(),o.settings.keyboardEnabled&&!o.settings.ticker&&t(document).keydown(function(t){
            return 39==t.keyCode?(P(t),!1):37==t.keyCode?(k(t),!1):void 0
        }
        )
    }
    ,v=function(){
        var e=0,s=t();
        if("vertical"==o.settings.mode||o.settings.adaptiveHeight)if(o.carousel){
            var n=1==o.settings.moveSlides?o.active.index:o.active.index*m();
            for(s=o.children.eq(n),i=1;
            i&lt;
            =o.settings.maxSlides-1;
            i++)s=s.add(n+i&gt;
            =o.children.length?o.children.eq(i-1):o.children.eq(n+i))
        }
        else s=o.children.eq(o.active.index);
        else s=o.children;
        return"vertical"==o.settings.mode?(s.each(function(){
            e+=t(this).outerHeight()
        }
        ),o.settings.slideMargin&gt;
        0&&(e+=o.settings.slideMargin*(o.settings.minSlides-1))):e=Math.max.apply(Math,s.map(function(){
            return t(this).outerHeight(!1)
        }
        ).get()),e
    }
    ,p=function(){
        var t="100%";
        return o.settings.slideWidth&gt;
        0&&(t="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?o.settings.maxSlides*o.settings.slideWidth+(o.settings.maxSlides-1)*o.settings.slideMargin:o.settings.slideWidth),t
    }
    ,u=function(){
        var t=o.settings.slideWidth,e=o.viewport.width();
        return 0==o.settings.slideWidth||o.settings.slideWidth&gt;
        e&&!o.carousel||"vertical"==o.settings.mode?t=e:o.settings.maxSlides&gt;
        1&&"horizontal"==o.settings.mode&&(e&gt;
        o.maxThreshold||e&lt;
        o.minThreshold&&(t=(e-o.settings.slideMargin*(o.settings.minSlides-1))/o.settings.minSlides)),t
    }
    ,f=function(){
        var t=1;
        if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode&&o.settings.slideWidth&gt;
        0)if(o.viewport.width()&lt;
        o.minThreshold)t=o.settings.minSlides;
        else if(o.viewport.width()&gt;
        o.maxThreshold)t=o.settings.maxSlides;
        else{
            var e=o.children.first().width();
            t=Math.floor(o.viewport.width()/e)
        }
        else"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&(t=o.settings.minSlides);
        return t
    }
    ,x=function(){
        var t=0;
        if(o.settings.moveSlides&gt;
        0)if(o.settings.infiniteLoop)t=o.children.length/m();
        else for(var e=0,i=0;
        e&lt;
        o.children.length;
        )++t,e=i+f(),i+=o.settings.moveSlides&lt;
        =f()?o.settings.moveSlides:f();
        else t=Math.ceil(o.children.length/f());
        return t
    }
    ,m=function(){
        return o.settings.moveSlides&gt;
        0&&o.settings.moveSlides&lt;
        =f()?o.settings.moveSlides:f()
    }
    ,S=function(){
        if(o.children.length&gt;
        o.settings.maxSlides&&o.active.last&&!o.settings.infiniteLoop){
            if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode){
                var t=o.children.last(),e=t.position();
                b(-(e.left-(o.viewport.width()-t.width())),"reset",0)
            }
            else if("vertical"==o.settings.mode){
                var i=o.children.length-o.settings.minSlides,e=o.children.eq(i).position();
                b(-e.top,"reset",0)
            }
        }
        else{
            var e=o.children.eq(o.active.index*m()).position();
            o.active.index==x()-1&&(o.active.last=!0),void 0!=e&&("horizontal"==o.settings.mode?b(-e.left,"reset",0):"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&b(-e.top,"reset",0))
        }
    }
    ,b=function(t,e,i,s){
        if(o.usingCSS){
            var n="vertical"==o.settings.mode?"translate3d(0, "+t+"px, 0)":"translate3d("+t+"px, 0, 0)";
            r.css("-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transition-duration",i/1e3+"s"),"slide"==e?(r.css(o.animProp,n),r.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",function(){
                r.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd"),D()
            }
            )):"reset"==e?r.css(o.animProp,n):"ticker"==e&&(r.css("-"+o.cssPrefix+"-transition-timing-function","linear"),r.css(o.animProp,n),r.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",function(){
                r.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd"),b(s.resetValue,"reset",0),N()
            }
            ))
        }
        else{
            var a={
            }
            ;
            a[o.animProp]=t,"slide"==e?r.animate(a,i,o.settings.easing,function(){
                D()
            }
            ):"reset"==e?r.css(o.animProp,t):"ticker"==e&&r.animate(a,speed,"linear",function(){
                b(s.resetValue,"reset",0),N()
            }
            )
        }
    }
    ,w=function(){
        for(var e="",i=x(),s=0;
        i&gt;
        s;
        s++){
            var n="";
            o.settings.buildPager&&t.isFunction(o.settings.buildPager)?(n=o.settings.buildPager(s),o.pagerEl.addClass("bx-custom-pager")):(n=s+1,o.pagerEl.addClass("bx-default-pager")),e+='<div class="bx-pager-item"><a href="" data-slide-index="'+s+'" class="bx-pager-link">'+n+"</a></div>"
        }
        o.pagerEl.html(e)
    }
    ,T=function(){
        o.settings.pagerCustom?o.pagerEl=t(o.settings.pagerCustom):(o.pagerEl=t('<div class="bx-pager" />'),o.settings.pagerSelector?t(o.settings.pagerSelector).html(o.pagerEl):o.controls.el.addClass("bx-has-pager").append(o.pagerEl),w()),o.pagerEl.delegate("a","click",q)
    }
    ,C=function(){
        o.controls.next=t('<a class="bx-next" href="">'+o.settings.nextText+"</a>"),o.controls.prev=t('<a class="bx-prev" href="">'+o.settings.prevText+"</a>"),o.controls.next.bind("click",P),o.controls.prev.bind("click",k),o.settings.nextSelector&&t(o.settings.nextSelector).append(o.controls.next),o.settings.prevSelector&&t(o.settings.prevSelector).append(o.controls.prev),o.settings.nextSelector||o.settings.prevSelector||(o.controls.directionEl=t('<div class="bx-controls-direction" />'),o.controls.directionEl.append(o.controls.prev).append(o.controls.next),o.controls.el.addClass("bx-has-controls-direction").append(o.controls.directionEl))
    }
    ,E=function(){
        o.controls.start=t('<div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-start" href="">'+o.settings.startText+"</a></div>"),o.controls.stop=t('<div class="bx-controls-auto-item"><a class="bx-stop" href="">'+o.settings.stopText+"</a></div>"),o.controls.autoEl=t('<div class="bx-controls-auto" />'),o.controls.autoEl.delegate(".bx-start","click",z),o.controls.autoEl.delegate(".bx-stop","click",M),o.settings.autoControlsCombine?o.controls.autoEl.append(o.controls.start):o.controls.autoEl.append(o.controls.start).append(o.controls.stop),o.settings.autoControlsSelector?t(o.settings.autoControlsSelector).html(o.controls.autoEl):o.controls.el.addClass("bx-has-controls-auto").append(o.controls.autoEl),A(o.settings.autoStart?"stop":"start")
    }
    ,y=function(){
        o.children.each(function(){
            var e=t(this).find("img:first").attr("title");
            void 0!=e&&(""+e).length&&t(this).append('<div class="bx-caption"><span>'+e+"</span></div>")
        }
        )
    }
    ,P=function(t){
        o.settings.auto&&r.stopAuto(),r.goToNextSlide(),t.preventDefault()
    }
    ,k=function(t){
        o.settings.auto&&r.stopAuto(),r.goToPrevSlide(),t.preventDefault()
    }
    ,z=function(t){
        r.startAuto(),t.preventDefault()
    }
    ,M=function(t){
        r.stopAuto(),t.preventDefault()
    }
    ,q=function(e){
        o.settings.auto&&r.stopAuto();
        var i=t(e.currentTarget),s=parseInt(i.attr("data-slide-index"));
        s!=o.active.index&&r.goToSlide(s),e.preventDefault()
    }
    ,I=function(e){
        var i=o.children.length;
        return"short"==o.settings.pagerType?(o.settings.maxSlides&gt;
        1&&(i=Math.ceil(o.children.length/o.settings.maxSlides)),void o.pagerEl.html(e+1+o.settings.pagerShortSeparator+i)):(o.pagerEl.find("a").removeClass("active"),void o.pagerEl.each(function(i,s){
            t(s).find("a").eq(e).addClass("active")
        }
        ))
    }
    ,D=function(){
        if(o.settings.infiniteLoop){
            var t="";
            0==o.active.index?t=o.children.eq(0).position():o.active.index==x()-1&&o.carousel?t=o.children.eq((x()-1)*m()).position():o.active.index==o.children.length-1&&(t=o.children.eq(o.children.length-1).position()),"horizontal"==o.settings.mode?b(-t.left,"reset",0):"vertical"==o.settings.mode&&b(-t.top,"reset",0)
        }
        o.working=!1,o.settings.onSlideAfter(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index)
    }
    ,A=function(t){
        o.settings.autoControlsCombine?o.controls.autoEl.html(o.controls[t]):(o.controls.autoEl.find("a").removeClass("active"),o.controls.autoEl.find("a:not(.bx-"+t+")").addClass("active"))
    }
    ,W=function(){
        1==x()?(o.controls.prev.addClass("disabled"),o.controls.next.addClass("disabled")):!o.settings.infiniteLoop&&o.settings.hideControlOnEnd&&(0==o.active.index?(o.controls.prev.addClass("disabled"),o.controls.next.removeClass("disabled")):o.active.index==x()-1?(o.controls.next.addClass("disabled"),o.controls.prev.removeClass("disabled")):(o.controls.prev.removeClass("disabled"),o.controls.next.removeClass("disabled")))
    }
    ,H=function(){
        if(o.settings.autoDelay&gt;
        0){
            setTimeout(r.startAuto,o.settings.autoDelay)
        }
        else r.startAuto();
        o.settings.autoHover&&r.hover(function(){
            o.interval&&(r.stopAuto(!0),o.autoPaused=!0)
        }
        ,function(){
            o.autoPaused&&(r.startAuto(!0),o.autoPaused=null)
        }
        )
    }
    ,L=function(){
        var e=0;
        if("next"==o.settings.autoDirection)r.append(o.children.clone().addClass("bx-clone"));
        else{
            r.prepend(o.children.clone().addClass("bx-clone"));
            var i=o.children.first().position();
            e="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-i.left:-i.top
        }
        b(e,"reset",0),o.settings.pager=!1,o.settings.controls=!1,o.settings.autoControls=!1,o.settings.tickerHover&&!o.usingCSS&&o.viewport.hover(function(){
            r.stop()
        }
        ,function(){
            var e=0;
            o.children.each(function(){
                e+="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?t(this).outerWidth(!0):t(this).outerHeight(!0)
            }
            );
            var i=o.settings.speed/e,s="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?"left":"top",n=i*(e-Math.abs(parseInt(r.css(s))));
            N(n)
        }
        ),N()
    }
    ,N=function(t){
        speed=t?t:o.settings.speed;
        var e={
            left:0,top:0
        }
        ,i={
            left:0,top:0
        }
        ;
        "next"==o.settings.autoDirection?e=r.find(".bx-clone").first().position():i=o.children.first().position();
        var s="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-e.left:-e.top,n="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-i.left:-i.top,a={
            resetValue:n
        }
        ;
        b(s,"ticker",speed,a)
    }
    ,O=function(){
        o.touch={
            start:{
                x:0,y:0
            }
            ,end:{
                x:0,y:0
            }
        }
        ,o.viewport.bind("touchstart",X)
    }
    ,X=function(t){
        if(o.working)t.preventDefault();
        else{
            o.touch.originalPos=r.position();
            var e=t.originalEvent;
            o.touch.start.x=e.changedTouches[0].pageX,o.touch.start.y=e.changedTouches[0].pageY,o.viewport.bind("touchmove",Y),o.viewport.bind("touchend",V)
        }
    }
    ,Y=function(t){
        var e=t.originalEvent,i=Math.abs(e.changedTouches[0].pageX-o.touch.start.x),s=Math.abs(e.changedTouches[0].pageY-o.touch.start.y);
        if(3*i&gt;
        s&&o.settings.preventDefaultSwipeX?t.preventDefault():3*s&gt;
        i&&o.settings.preventDefaultSwipeY&&t.preventDefault(),"fade"!=o.settings.mode&&o.settings.oneToOneTouch){
            var n=0;
            if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode){
                var r=e.changedTouches[0].pageX-o.touch.start.x;
                n=o.touch.originalPos.left+r
            }
            else{
                var r=e.changedTouches[0].pageY-o.touch.start.y;
                n=o.touch.originalPos.top+r
            }
            b(n,"reset",0)
        }
    }
    ,V=function(t){
        o.viewport.unbind("touchmove",Y);
        var e=t.originalEvent,i=0;
        if(o.touch.end.x=e.changedTouches[0].pageX,o.touch.end.y=e.changedTouches[0].pageY,"fade"==o.settings.mode){
            var s=Math.abs(o.touch.start.x-o.touch.end.x);
            s&gt;
            =o.settings.swipeThreshold&&(o.touch.start.x&gt;
            o.touch.end.x?r.goToNextSlide():r.goToPrevSlide(),r.stopAuto())
        }
        else{
            var s=0;
            "horizontal"==o.settings.mode?(s=o.touch.end.x-o.touch.start.x,i=o.touch.originalPos.left):(s=o.touch.end.y-o.touch.start.y,i=o.touch.originalPos.top),!o.settings.infiniteLoop&&(0==o.active.index&&s&gt;
            0||o.active.last&&0&gt;
            s)?b(i,"reset",200):Math.abs(s)&gt;
            =o.settings.swipeThreshold?(0&gt;
            s?r.goToNextSlide():r.goToPrevSlide(),r.stopAuto()):b(i,"reset",200)
        }
        o.viewport.unbind("touchend",V)
    }
    ,B=function(){
        var e=t(window).width(),i=t(window).height();
        (a!=e||l!=i)&&(a=e,l=i,r.redrawSlider())
    }
    ;
    return r.goToSlide=function(e,i){
        if(!o.working&&o.active.index!=e)if(o.working=!0,o.oldIndex=o.active.index,o.active.index=0&gt;
        e?x()-1:e&gt;
        =x()?0:e,o.settings.onSlideBefore(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index),"next"==i?o.settings.onSlideNext(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index):"prev"==i&&o.settings.onSlidePrev(o.children.eq(o.active.index),o.oldIndex,o.active.index),o.active.last=o.active.index&gt;
        =x()-1,o.settings.pager&&I(o.active.index),o.settings.controls&&W(),"fade"==o.settings.mode)o.settings.adaptiveHeight&&o.viewport.height()!=v()&&o.viewport.animate({
            height:v()
        }
        ,o.settings.adaptiveHeightSpeed),o.children.filter(":visible").fadeOut(o.settings.speed).css({
            zIndex:0
        }
        ),o.children.eq(o.active.index).css("zIndex",51).fadeIn(o.settings.speed,function(){
            t(this).css("zIndex",50),D()
        }
        );
        else{
            o.settings.adaptiveHeight&&o.viewport.height()!=v()&&o.viewport.animate({
                height:v()
            }
            ,o.settings.adaptiveHeightSpeed);
            var s=0,n={
                left:0,top:0
            }
            ;
            if(!o.settings.infiniteLoop&&o.carousel&&o.active.last)if("horizontal"==o.settings.mode){
                var a=o.children.eq(o.children.length-1);
                n=a.position(),s=o.viewport.width()-a.outerWidth()
            }
            else{
                var l=o.children.length-o.settings.minSlides;
                n=o.children.eq(l).position()
            }
            else if(o.carousel&&o.active.last&&"prev"==i){
                var d=1==o.settings.moveSlides?o.settings.maxSlides-m():(x()-1)*m()-(o.children.length-o.settings.maxSlides),a=r.children(".bx-clone").eq(d);
                n=a.position()
            }
            else if("next"==i&&0==o.active.index)n=r.find("&gt;
            .bx-clone").eq(o.settings.maxSlides).position(),o.active.last=!1;
            else if(e&gt;
            =0){
                var c=e*m();
                n=o.children.eq(c).position()
            }
            if("undefined"!=typeof n){
                var g="horizontal"==o.settings.mode?-(n.left-s):-n.top;
                b(g,"slide",o.settings.speed)
            }
        }
    }
    ,r.goToNextSlide=function(){
        if(o.settings.infiniteLoop||!o.active.last){
            var t=parseInt(o.active.index)+1;
            r.goToSlide(t,"next")
        }
    }
    ,r.goToPrevSlide=function(){
        if(o.settings.infiniteLoop||0!=o.active.index){
            var t=parseInt(o.active.index)-1;
            r.goToSlide(t,"prev")
        }
    }
    ,r.startAuto=function(t){
        o.interval||(o.interval=setInterval(function(){
            "next"==o.settings.autoDirection?r.goToNextSlide():r.goToPrevSlide()
        }
        ,o.settings.pause),o.settings.autoControls&&1!=t&&A("stop"))
    }
    ,r.stopAuto=function(t){
        o.interval&&(clearInterval(o.interval),o.interval=null,o.settings.autoControls&&1!=t&&A("start"))
    }
    ,r.getCurrentSlide=function(){
        return o.active.index
    }
    ,r.getSlideCount=function(){
        return o.children.length
    }
    ,r.redrawSlider=function(){
        o.children.add(r.find(".bx-clone")).outerWidth(u()),o.viewport.css("height",v()),o.settings.ticker||S(),o.active.last&&(o.active.index=x()-1),o.active.index&gt;
        =x()&&(o.active.last=!0),o.settings.pager&&!o.settings.pagerCustom&&(w(),I(o.active.index))
    }
    ,r.destroySlider=function(){
        o.initialized&&(o.initialized=!1,t(".bx-clone",this).remove(),o.children.each(function(){
            void 0!=t(this).data("origStyle")?t(this).attr("style",t(this).data("origStyle")):t(this).removeAttr("style")
        }
        ),void 0!=t(this).data("origStyle")?this.attr("style",t(this).data("origStyle")):t(this).removeAttr("style"),t(this).unwrap().unwrap(),o.controls.el&&o.controls.el.remove(),o.controls.next&&o.controls.next.remove(),o.controls.prev&&o.controls.prev.remove(),o.pagerEl&&o.pagerEl.remove(),t(".bx-caption",this).remove(),o.controls.autoEl&&o.controls.autoEl.remove(),clearInterval(o.interval),o.settings.responsive&&t(window).unbind("resize",B))
    }
    ,r.reloadSlider=function(t){
        void 0!=t&&(n=t),r.destroySlider(),d()
    }
    ,d(),this
}
}
(jQuery);
```